# Se puede instalar la libreria dlib en google coral dev board?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Buenas a todos quisiera recurrir a la sabiduria de ustedes, como estoy actualmente trabajando en mi proyecto final de grado, quisiera saber si fuera posible instalar la libereria dlib http://dlib.net/ en el nuevo sistema embedido de google "Google coral dev board" ( [https://www.amazon.com/Generic-NA-Google-Coral-Board/dp/B07PK2XVM6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PK2XVM6)), se que funciona en raspberry pi , pero me surge la duda ya que la misma solamente soporta tensorflow lite, desde ya muchas gracias por la respuesta.